# Angular6 and ng2-charts does not display any charts when i fill data from webservice

Tags: angular, chart.js, ng2-charts

i need to implement some charts in my project but when i fill data from webservice it does not show anything, can any body tell me why it happened and how can i solve this problem ??

My component is :

```ts
import { ChartService } from './../../services/chart.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  public doughnutChartLabels: string[] = ['Download Sales', 'In-Store Sales', 'Mail-Order Sales'];
  public doughnutChartData: number[] = [350, 450, 100];

  public countriesLabel: string[] = new Array();
  public countriestData: number[] = new Array();

  doughnutChartType = 'doughnut';

  constructor(private chartService: ChartService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.chartService.getCountryGroupBy().subscribe(data => {

        data.data.forEach(country => {
          this.countriestData.push(country.count);
          this.countriesLabel.push(country.country);
        });

    });
  }
```

View : home.component.html

```html
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <div style="display: block">
        <canvas baseChart
                    [data]="countriestData"
                    [labels]="countriesLabel"
                    [chartType]="doughnutChartType"></canvas>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <div style="display: block">
        <canvas baseChart
                    [data]="doughnutChartData"
                    [labels]="doughnutChartLabels"
                    [chartType]="doughnutChartType"></canvas>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

serive : ChartService.ts

```ts
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Config } from './../libs/config';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/internal/operators';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ChartService {

  baseUrl = `${this.config.baseUrl}/chart`;
  constructor(private config: Config, private http: HttpClient) { }

    get setHeader(): HttpHeaders {
      const headersConfig = {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Accept': 'application/json'
      };
      return new HttpHeaders( headersConfig );
    }

  getCountryGroupBy() {
    return this.http.get<any>(`${this.baseUrl}/countries`, {
      headers: this.setHeader,
      withCredentials: true}).pipe(
        map(response => {
            return response;
          }),
        catchError(this.handleError)
      );
  }

  handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    console.error('server error:', error);
    if (error.error instanceof Error) {
      const errMessage = error.error.message;
      return Observable.throw(errMessage);
      // Use the following instead if using lite-server
      // return Observable.throw(err.text() || 'backend server error');
    }
    return Observable.throw(error || 'Server error');
  }

}
```

and my webservice return :

> {    "status":200,    "data":[
>         {
>            "count":30,
>            "country":"FR"
>         },
>         {
>            "count":13,
>            "country":"NL"
>         },
>         {
>            "count":4,
>            "country":"IR"
>         }    ],    "message":null }

in this case first chart does not show anything and second one work successfully !!!!
some ideas ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

The chart itself seems fine, so I guess the problem is the way you try to fill your arrays.

You have checked the content of `countriestData` and `countriesLabel`?

You didn't show what exactly `chartService.getCountryGroupBy()` returns, but I guess it's only the response body of the request, so you'll probably have to change your code to

```
this.chartService.getCountryGroupBy().subscribe(data => {

    data.forEach(country => {
      this.countriestData.push(country.count);
      this.countriesLabel.push(country.country);
    });

});
```

Comment: dear @sloth thanks for your response, yes i check countriesData and countriesLabel by console.log and both of them are correct , and getCountryGroupBy return exactly what my webservice return, so i must use data.data for fill my arrays

Comment: @arashDman Take a look at this [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ondtsq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts). I just copy pasted your code, and it works fine. So I guess the problem has to be the data. Could you show the code of `getCountryGroupBy()`?

Comment: thanks to your response again, getCountryGroupBy() added to my question

Comment: @arashDman if you print out `reponse` in `getCountryGroupBy`, do you really see `{ "status":200, "data":[ { "count":30, "country":"FR" }, { "count":13, "country":"NL" }, { "count":4, "country":"IR" } ], "message":null }`? It just seems very strange to me to include the status code in the reponse body...

Comment: yes when i call my webservice in my browser i get this response too.
status code use for some other reason

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public countriesLabel: string[] = [{ data: [] }];
public countriestData: number[] = [{ data: [] }];
```

or

```
public countriesLabel: any[] = [{ data: [] }];
public countriestData: any[] = [{ data: [] }];
```

I could solve my similar problem by changing the definition of my data to this format.